# Recognize only one or more letters using Tesseract (Tes4J), bug with A or less than 4 letters

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Basically my problem is that I need a solution that reads either one or more letters. I've done some things so far, and it was working perfectly, I had a confgFile with two lines:

- load_system_dawg F
- load_freq_dawg F

I added them while looking for some configs that would help me. As I said, everything was working fine, until yesterday when I was looking for something to block the reading of numbers and special characters. I made some tests but they weren't working, when suddenly nothing was working anymore, Tesseract was no longer recognizing less than 4 letters, unless the letter 'A' was among them. So I moved to an old version, without those new configs and this is what started happening:

1. Tesseract no longer recognizes less than 4 letters (sometimes it must be at least 5), I had tested each letter before, and it was working perfectly (needed only some adjustments for letter C and Q)
2. It'll recognize anything (be it 2, 3 or 4 letters) if the letter 'A' is among the letters. Only the letter 'A' makes that happen.
3. It simply no longer recognizes only one letters, except for letter 'A'

Here is my Tesseract code:

```
public String tRun(){
    instance = new Tesseract();   // Tesseract instance;
    List<String> configs = Arrays.asList("addConfig");  // configFile with those 2 options

    instance.setConfigs(configs);
    instance.setLanguage("eng");

    result = "";
    try {
        result = instance.doOCR(image);  // previously loaded   
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Resultado: " + result);

    return result;
}
```

And here I have some of the tests I did, following what I said: if it's less than 4~5 letters, without letter A, it gives a blank result, if it has any size (be it 1 or more letters) with the letter A it gives me the right result.

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs1Zj.jpg